# BleachBit not working properly

Tags: bleachbit

Whenever I run bleachbit , it doesn't work fully. It creates an error message. One of the message being ' You are not superuser'. Another message is 'Errno13'.
Please guide in the matter.

Comment: Have you tried running it with `sudo` (as superuser)?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the little grey **☑** under the number now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

**Terminal:**

I don't know about the second error, but the first one (unless you are already doing so) should be solved by running it as superuser by running it with this in Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo bleachbit
```

(It will prompt you then for a password, type it and press enter - for a security measure it will look like you are not typing anything, but you are.)

**GUI:**

Alternatively you could run it as superuser by searching for the application `BleachBit (as root)` and clicking on that as opposed to just the normal `BleachBit`.